# Assigning each column in a csv file to an array

Tags: bash, csv, import

```
NameColumn1;NameColumn2;NameColumn3;NameColumn4
Row1;Row1;Row1;Row1;
Row2;Row2;Row2;Row2;
Row3;Row3;Row3;Row3;
```

I came across an example where someone wanted to take the following information (above) and store them in variables. The solution was to create a loop that would append the data all into regular variables as such:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS=';' read -ra array; do
  ar1+=("${array[0]}")
  ar2+=("${array[1]}")
  ar3+=("${array[2]}")
  ar4+=("${array[3]}")
done < file.csv
```

Instead of ar1-4 containing all data in each column, I would prefer to have this data separated in an array such that I would have a col1(x), col2(x), col3(x), col4(x) and x would represent the row that would contain a single value. Is this possible in bash?

I tried to create my own version but I'm receiving an error that says "cannot assign list to array member". Here is the modified version that produces the error message. The first value in the first row contains the header. I checked the value by inserting "echo ${array[0]}" into the loop and it shows "Employee Payroll" (without the quotes) :

```
  while IFS=, read -ra array
  do
    col1[$x]=("${array[0]}")
    col2[$x]=("${array[1]}")
    col3[$x]=("${array[2]}")
    col4[$x]=("${array[3]}")
    col5[$x]=("${array[4]}")
    col6[$x]=("${array[5]}")
    col7[$x]=("${array[6]}")
    col8[$x]=("${array[7]}")
    x+=1
  done < "$importfile"
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to assign a one-cell array value (`"${array[0]}"`) to an array cell (`col1[$x]`). Bash does not support arrays of arrays. Use `col1[$x]="${array[0]}"`, instead. Note that what you try to do is the same as the original, in a slightly less elegant way. You can check this by running your first shell script and then: `echo "${!ar1[@]}"` to see the indices of array `ar1` and `echo "${ar1[@]}"` to see its values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, removing the (" ") around the word array fixed the issue. Here's is the working code.

```
  while IFS=, read -ra array
  do
    echo ${array[0]}
    col1[$x]=${array[0]}
    col2[$x]=${array[1]}
    col3[$x]=${array[2]}
    col4[$x]=${array[3]}
    col5[$x]=${array[4]}
    col6[$x]=${array[5]}
    col7[$x]=${array[6]}
    col8[$x]=${array[7]}
    x+=1
  done < "$importfile"
```